# python regex- match anything but certain characters (can't avoid hyphen to match either escaped, at the beginning or end of the character class)

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to check if there is any character but a specific set in a string using python regex. I've read other answers that conclude that hyphens can be either escaped or placed either at the beggining or end of the character class. I've tried all of them but still can't avoid the hyphen to match:

```
import regex as re
exclude_pat = r'[^-\d\.,%]+'
re.search(exclude_pat, '‐61,37%')
```

Comment: your minuses are different; See: `https://regex101.com/r/8wKJDX/latest`. `[^-‐\d\.,%]+` will work appropriatly